# TDE in Azure on a virtual server

Tags: sql-server-2012

Our new system handle HIPPA data and has security equirements. 
Azure handles secure connections, but we're looking at TDE as well.

One of our consultants said that TDE is possible by creating a virtual server in Azure and loading SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition directly on to the server. This would be outside of the Azure provisioning.  Would this work?

I know that a recent release  that's currently in preview that would accomodate TDE. Does any one know were I can get the preview version?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I'm assuming you're referring to running SQL Server in an Azure VM. If that's correct, TDE has nothing to do with Azure provisioning.

You can pick any of the SQL Server VM templates available that supports TDE. After Azure completes provision of the VM, you can login to your SQL Server and enable TDE. You can certainly still upload your own VM image but unless you have some corporate standards, pre-installed software, etc... a regular provision is probably the easiest and fastest.